# How to install moka theme and icon packs?

Tags: themes

How do I install the "moka" icon pack on Ubuntu 14.04 and a theme pack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding **Noobslab** PPA to your sources, in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
```

To preview themes and icon packs for Ubuntu 14.04 go [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/themes-collection-for-ubuntu-1110-unity.html)

Comment: I get "add-get command not found" - I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Comment: No :( I tried and it still doesn't recognize the command "apt-get update"

Comment: do you run `sudo` before command?

Comment: Yeah :( I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 now :(

Comment: @user284848 Ubuntu 13.10 is outside of support. I recommend that you upgrade to 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Moka theme and icon theme packs are available separately, and you can follow the instructions at mokaproject.com.

Numix is another option for Ubuntu 14.04, available at numixproject.com

Answer (score 0):

This is how to install theme packs, not icon packs because I haven't learned that:

1. Download some theme from www.gnome-looks.org
   example:`http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+8+modern+UI?content=157024`
2. Open  the terminal. -- Ctrl+Alt+T and run:

   ```
   gksu nautilus
   ```
3. Type the password.
4. Open another window of Nautilus
5. Extract the file, example: windows8.tar.gz and copy it to `/usr/share/themes/` in the root window that you opened from the terminal.
6. Open GNOME Tweak Tool and setup GTK+ and Window with the theme pack you have downloaded. If you don't have GNOME Tweak Tool installed, search for it in the Ubuntu Software Center.